# Compare list of dictionaries with variable number of dictionaries in each list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries as:

```
list1 = [
    {'vehicle': 1, 'mileage': 25, 'speed': 80}, 
    {'vehicle': 2, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 70},
    {'vehicle': 3, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 90},
    {'vehicle': 5, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 90}
]

list2 = [
    {'vehicle': 1, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 80}, 
    {'vehicle': 2, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 70},
    {'vehicle': 3, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 80},
    {'vehicle': 4, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 80}
]
```

I have to print dictionaries from list1 if vechiles of same name is on list2 and mileage and speed of corresponding vehilce is greater than or equal to that of in list2.
In this example, output should be:

```
[{'vehicle': 1, 'mileage': 25, 'speed': 80}, 
 {'vehicle': 2, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 70}]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? You can nest two loops and check if the current values match your requirements. If this is true, add the value to an empty list otherwise keep going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do create a lookup dictionary to search for the corresponding matches in `O(1)`:

```
list1 = [{'vehicle': 1, 'mileage': 25, 'speed': 80},
         {'vehicle': 2, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 70},
         {'vehicle': 3, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 90},
         {'vehicle': 5, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 90}]

list2 = [{'vehicle': 1, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 80},
         {'vehicle': 2, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 70},
         {'vehicle': 3, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 80},
         {'vehicle': 4, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 80}]


lookup = {e['vehicle'] : e for e in list1 }

result = []
for e in list2 :
    if e['vehicle'] in lookup:
        d = lookup[e['vehicle']]
        if e['mileage'] >= d['mileage'] and e['speed'] >= d['speed']:
            result.append(d)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'vehicle': 1, 'mileage': 25, 'speed': 80}, {'vehicle': 2, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 70}]
```

An alternative using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def better(e, d, keys=('mileage', 'speed')):
    return all(e[k] >= d[k] for k in keys)


result = [lookup[e['vehicle']] for e in list2 if e['vehicle'] in lookup and better(e, lookup[e['vehicle']])]

print(result)
```

The overall complexity of both approaches is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your list of dicts to nested dicts, where `vehicle` is the key:

```
list1 = [
    {"vehicle": 1, "mileage": 25, "speed": 80},
    {"vehicle": 2, "mileage": 35, "speed": 70},
    {"vehicle": 3, "mileage": 40, "speed": 90},
    {"vehicle": 5, "mileage": 40, "speed": 90},
]

list2 = [
    {"vehicle": 1, "mileage": 35, "speed": 80},
    {"vehicle": 2, "mileage": 35, "speed": 70},
    {"vehicle": 3, "mileage": 40, "speed": 80},
    {"vehicle": 4, "mileage": 40, "speed": 80},
]

dict1 = {x["vehicle"]: x for x in list1}
# {1: {'vehicle': 1, 'mileage': 25, 'speed': 80}, 2: {'vehicle': 2, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 70}, 3: {'vehicle': 3, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 90}, 5: {'vehicle': 5, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 90}}

dict2 = {x["vehicle"]: x for x in list2}
# {1: {'vehicle': 1, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 80}, 2: {'vehicle': 2, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 70}, 3: {'vehicle': 3, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 80}, 4: {'vehicle': 4, 'mileage': 40, 'speed': 80}}
```

Then take the intersection of keys and return the result as a list of dicts using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
result = [
    dict1[k]
    for k in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()
    if dict2[k]["mileage"] >= dict1[k]["mileage"]
    and dict2[k]["speed"] >= dict1[k]["speed"]
]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'vehicle': 1, 'mileage': 25, 'speed': 80}, {'vehicle': 2, 'mileage': 35, 'speed': 70}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use pandas Dataframe.
Not the most effecient but very readable

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)
result_df = df1[(df1.vehicle.isin(df2.vehicle)) & (df1.speed <= df2.speed) & (df1.mileage <= df2.mileage)]
result_list = result_df.to_dict('records')

print(result_list)
```

output:

```
[{'mileage': 25, 'speed': 80, 'vehicle': 1},
 {'mileage': 35, 'speed': 70, 'vehicle': 2}]
```